# Can't install Ruby 2.0.0 through RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have inherited a legacy codebase that requires Ruby 2.0.0 to be installed with RVM. I am on Mac OS X Catalina, and the installer for Ruby 2.0.0 simply doesn't work.

Here is what my installation attempts look like, all the way from the installation of RVM itself up to the attempted Ruby 2.0.0 installation.

```
nbyrd$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.29.10.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.10/1.29.10.tar.gz.asc
gpg: Signature made Wed Mar 25 14:58:42 2020 PDT
gpg:                using RSA key 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
gpg: Good signature from "Piotr Kuczynski <piotr.kuczynski@gmail.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 7D2B AF1C F37B 13E2 069D  6956 105B D0E7 3949 9BDB
GPG verified '/Users/nbyrd/.rvm/archives/rvm-1.29.10.tgz'
Installing RVM to /Users/nbyrd/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/nbyrd/.mkshrc.
    RVM PATH line not found for Bash or Zsh, rerun this command with '--auto-dotfiles' flag to fix it.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/nbyrd/.profile /Users/nbyrd/.bash_profile /Users/nbyrd/.zlogin.
Installation of RVM in /Users/nbyrd/.rvm/ is almost complete:

  * To start using RVM you need to run `source /Users/nbyrd/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
    in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.
Thanks for installing RVM 
Please consider donating to our open collective to help us maintain RVM.

  Donate: https://opencollective.com/rvm/donate


nbyrd$ source ~/.profile
nbyrd$ rvm autolibs enable
nbyrd$ rvm install 2.0.0 --force
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.15/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p648.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system.......
Installing required packages: openssl.
Updating certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem'
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/nbyrd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p648, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 10.2M  100 10.2M    0     0  18.2M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 18.2M
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #extracting ruby-2.0.0-p648 to /Users/nbyrd/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p648.....
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #applying patch /Users/nbyrd/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.0.0/openssl3.patch.
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #applying patch /Users/nbyrd/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.0.0/update-autoconf.patch.
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #configuring.................................................
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #compiling......................
Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
please read /Users/nbyrd/.rvm/log/1605305278_ruby-2.0.0-p648/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

And here is the contents of the "make.log" file referenced in the error message:

```
[2020-11-13 14:09:14] __rvm_make
__rvm_make () 
{ 
    \make "$@" || return $?
}
current path: /Users/nbyrd/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p648
PATH=/usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin:/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/nbyrd/.yarn/bin:/Users/nbyrd/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/nbyrd/.yarn/bin:/Users/nbyrd/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/nbyrd/.yarn/bin:/Users/nbyrd/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:/Users/nbyrd/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/nbyrd/.rvm/bin
command(2): __rvm_make -j8
++ make -j8
    CC = /usr/bin/clang
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = /usr/bin/clang -dynamiclib
    CFLAGS = -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration   -fno-common -pipe 
    XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
    CPPFLAGS = -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin19.6.0 -I./include -I.
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib  -install_name /Users/nbyrd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/libruby.2.0.0.dylib -current_version 2.0.0 -compatibility_version 2.0.0  -fstack-protector -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend  -fstack-protector -Wl,-u,_objc_msgSend  
    SOLIBS = 
compiling main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling dmyencoding.c
compiling version.c
compiling miniprelude.c
translating probes probes.d
compiling bignum.c
compiling class.c
. ./vm_opts.h
compiling compar.c
compiling complex.c
compiling dir.c
compiling dln_find.c
compiling enum.c
complex.c:79:1: warning: unused function 'f_cmp' [-Wunused-function]
f_cmp(VALUE x, VALUE y)
^
complex.c:109:1: warning: unused function 'f_lt_p' [-Wunused-function]
f_lt_p(VALUE x, VALUE y)
^
complex.c:116:1: warning: unused function 'f_mod' [-Wunused-function]
binop(mod, '%')
^
complex.c:30:21: note: expanded from macro 'binop'
inline static VALUE \
                    ^
<scratch space>:89:1: note: expanded from here
f_mod
^
complex.c:155:1: warning: unused function 'f_abs2' [-Wunused-function]
fun1(abs2)
^
complex.c:37:21: note: expanded from macro 'fun1'
inline static VALUE \
                    ^
<scratch space>:92:1: note: expanded from here
f_abs2
^
complex.c:157:1: warning: unused function 'f_conj' [-Wunused-function]
fun1(conj)
^
complex.c:37:21: note: expanded from macro 'fun1'
inline static VALUE \
                    ^
<scratch space>:96:1: note: expanded from here
f_conj
^
complex.c:159:1: warning: unused function 'f_floor' [-Wunused-function]
fun1(floor)
^
complex.c:37:21: note: expanded from macro 'fun1'
inline static VALUE \
                    ^
<scratch space>:100:1: note: expanded from here
f_floor
^
complex.c:160:1: warning: unused function 'f_imag' [-Wunused-function]
fun1(imag)
^
complex.c:37:21: note: expanded from macro 'fun1'
inline static VALUE \
                    ^
<scratch space>:102:1: note: expanded from here
f_imag
^
complex.c:164:1: warning: unused function 'f_real' [-Wunused-function]
fun1(real)
^
complex.c:37:21: note: expanded from macro 'fun1'
inline static VALUE \
                    ^
<scratch space>:110:1: note: expanded from here
f_real
^
complex.c:185:1: warning: unused function 'f_divmod' [-Wunused-function]
fun2(divmod)
^
complex.c:44:21: note: expanded from macro 'fun2'
inline static VALUE \
                    ^
<scratch space>:118:1: note: expanded from here
f_divmod
^
complex.c:197:1: warning: unused function 'f_idiv' [-Wunused-function]
fun2(idiv)
^
complex.c:44:21: note: expanded from macro 'fun2'
inline static VALUE \
                    ^
<scratch space>:124:1: note: expanded from here
f_idiv
^
complex.c:263:1: warning: unused function 'k_integer_p' [-Wunused-function]
k_integer_p(VALUE x)
^
complex.c:465:1: warning: unused function 'f_complex_new1' [-Wunused-function]
f_complex_new1(VALUE klass, VALUE x)
^
complex.c:547:1: warning: unused function 'm_sqrt_bang' [-Wunused-function]
imp1(sqrt)
^
complex.c:518:21: note: expanded from macro 'imp1'
inline static VALUE \
                    ^
<scratch space>:150:1: note: expanded from here
m_sqrt_bang
^
bignum.c:910:1: warning: unused function 'next_pow2' [-Wunused-function]
next_pow2(register unsigned long x)
^
compiling enumerator.c
compiling error.c
compiling eval.c
compiling load.c
compiling proc.c
compiling file.c
compiling gc.c
13 warnings generated.
compiling hash.c
compiling inits.c
compiling io.c
compiling marshal.c
compiling math.c
compiling node.c
compiling numeric.c
compiling object.c
compiling pack.c
compiling parse.c
compiling process.c
compiling random.c
compiling range.c
compiling rational.c
rational.c:86:1: warning: unused function 'f_gt_p' [-Wunused-function]
f_gt_p(VALUE x, VALUE y)
^
rational.c:136:1: warning: unused function 'f_floor' [-Wunused-function]
fun1(floor)
^
rational.c:40:21: note: expanded from macro 'fun1'
inline static VALUE \
                    ^
<scratch space>:93:1: note: expanded from here
f_floor
^
rational.c:157:1: warning: unused function 'f_truncate' [-Wunused-function]
fun1(truncate)
^
rational.c:40:21: note: expanded from macro 'fun1'
inline static VALUE \
                    ^
<scratch space>:103:1: note: expanded from here
f_truncate
^
rational.c:428:1: warning: unused function 'f_rational_new_bang2' [-Wunused-function]
f_rational_new_bang2(VALUE klass, VALUE x, VALUE y)
^
rational.c:537:1: warning: unused function 'f_rational_new1' [-Wunused-function]
f_rational_new1(VALUE klass, VALUE x)
^
rational.c:552:1: warning: unused function 'f_rational_new_no_reduce1' [-Wunused-function]
f_rational_new_no_reduce1(VALUE klass, VALUE x)
^
1 warning generated.
compiling re.c
compiling regcomp.c
compiling regenc.c
compiling regerror.c
compiling regexec.c
compiling regparse.c
compiling regsyntax.c
compiling ruby.c
6 warnings generated.
compiling safe.c
compiling signal.c
compiling sprintf.c
compiling st.c
compiling strftime.c
compiling string.c
compiling struct.c
compiling time.c
compiling transcode.c
compiling util.c
compiling variable.c
compiling compile.c
compiling debug.c
compiling iseq.c
compiling vm.c
compiling vm_dump.c
compiling vm_backtrace.c
compiling vm_trace.c
compiling thread.c
vm.c:1916:31: warning: expression does not compute the number of elements in this array; element type is 'int', not 'VALUE' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsizeof-array-div]
                                 sizeof(th->machine_regs) / sizeof(VALUE));
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
vm.c:1916:31: note: place parentheses around the 'sizeof(VALUE)' expression to silence this warning
thread.c:977:27: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to '__darwin_suseconds_t' (aka 'int') [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        tp->tv_usec = ts.tv_nsec / 1000;
                    ~ ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
thread.c:4835:20: error: implicit declaration of function 'rb_frame_last_func' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    const ID mid = rb_frame_last_func();
                   ^
thread.c:4835:20: note: did you mean 'rb_frame_this_func'?
./include/ruby/intern.h:369:4: note: 'rb_frame_this_func' declared here
ID rb_frame_this_func(void);
   ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [thread.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
1 warning generated.
++ return 2
```

I genuinely don't know what I can do to get past this error. I have never worked with Ruby before, but it looks like there is a function-call in its source code for which there is no function-declaration ("rb_frame_last_func").

I have tried multiple C-compilers and none of them have worked. I also tried getting help from the RVM developers, but they simply have not responded to my questions. RVM's website has no details on these errors. And I have browsed Stackoverflow and Google and tried dozens of alternative approaches: none of which have worked.

Can someone tell me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 5):

This is due to a change in the behavior of tools included with Xcode 12:

> Clang now reports an error when you use a function without an explicit declaration when building C or Objective-C code for macOS (-Werror=implicit-function-declaration flag is on). This additional error detection unifies Clang’s behavior for iOS/tvOS and macOS 64-bit targets for this diagnostic. (49917738)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12-release-notes

You'll probably want to pass [compile flags](https://rvm.io/rubies/installing) to RVM by setting them in your environment:

```sh
export optflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```

Then you can retry:

```
$ rvm install 2.0.0
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.15/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p648.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Warning: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is deprecated! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system - please wait
Installing required packages: openssl - please wait
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/foo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p648, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #extracting ruby-2.0.0-p648 to /Users/foo/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p648 - please wait
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #applying patch /Users/foo/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.0.0/openssl3.patch - please wait
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #applying patch /Users/foo/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.0.0/update-autoconf.patch - please wait
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #configuring - please wait
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #post-configuration - please wait
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #compiling - please wait
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #installing - please wait
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #making binaries executable - please wait
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #downloading rubygems-3.0.8
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #extracting rubygems-3.0.8 - please wait
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #removing old rubygems - please wait
ruby-2.0.0-p648 - #installing rubygems-3.0.8 - please wait
Error running 'env GEM_HOME=/Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648@global GEM_PATH= /Users/foo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/ruby -d /Users/foo/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.8/setup.rb --no-document',
please read /Users/foo/.rvm/log/1605308161_ruby-2.0.0-p648/rubygems.install.log
```

Despite the error at the end, Ruby does successfully compile and install:

```
$ rvm list
   ruby-2.0.0-p648 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.5.7 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.7.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-3.0.0-preview1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
$ rvm use 2.0.0
rvm use 2.0.0
Using /Users/foo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648
YAML safe loading is not available. Please upgrade psych to a version that supports safe loading (>= 2.0).
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [x86_64-darwin19.6.0]
```

The same fix is probably needed for gems with native extensions:

```sh
gem install some_gem_name --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```

Or for apps using bundler:

```sh
bundle config build.some_gem_name --with-cflags=\"-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration\"
```

Comment: I'm not so sure that this worked. The next step that I have to perform according to the legacy documentation is to install compass 1.0.3 with `gem install compass -v 1.0.3 --no-ri --no-rdoc`. This fails, even with your suggestion. See: https://pastebin.com/WbfcMkPJ

Comment: I can confirm that it does work — meaning Ruby can be compiled with the given flags — which answers your question. If you have a different question about a different problem beyond the scope of your original question then you should make a new post for that.

Comment: I have never worked with Ruby before, so forgive me if I am wrong; but is Gem not a native part of Ruby? If that isn't working, I don't consider it a successful installation...

Comment: No, `gem` is not a native part of Ruby. It is part of [rubygems](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/bin/gem) and is written in pure Ruby. The problem you have is that you have successfully installed Ruby but installing rubygems is failing because of an issue with OpenSSL. Neither of those things are related to building or installing Ruby, and neither of those things was asked in your original question. You have a new question and you should make a new post rather than [moving the goalposts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/393723).

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed in RVM. Use

```
rvm get master
```

To get newest version of rvm and run rvm install again.

Here is the source: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/pull/4995

Comment: This is still happening to me on OSX 10.15.7.

Comment: this is still happening for me on OSX 11.3.1, and after running `rvm get master`

Answer (score 0):

I got this working locally (in MacOS Sonoma - 14.x, on an x86_64 based machine, with XCode Tools 15.x) with some work and some hints/help from https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/discussions/1883.

I also have to maintain an *ancient* (and air-gapped) system that uses Ruby 2.1.9 in this case.

One of the problems is that Ruby before 2.4.x (I think) doesn't work with Openssl 1.1 or later.  MacOS now comes with OpenSSL 3.x or later (really, it's LibreSSL 3.x).  Generally, the process is

1. Install openssl 1.0.x libraries into a side location
2. Use appropriate flags and library paths when compiling Ruby (2.1.9 in my case)
3. Use appropriate versions of the rubygems_update and bundler for your Ruby version.

I needed the following tools:

- XCode CLI Tools - you can get them via `xcode-select --install`
- `rvm` - see https://rvm.io/ for more details on how to get it.
- `homebrew` - see https://brew.sh/ for more details on how to get it

  - I also need the `gpg` tool (to import the `rvm` gpg keys).  Installed through `brew install gpg` for me.

Basically, I had to install an old version of openssl via a clever (or not so clever) hack:

```
$ brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0
$ CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rvm install 2.1.9 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0
$ gem update --system 2.7.10
$ gem install bundler --version 1.17.3
$ bundle install
```

Since I need Ruby 2.1.9, I had to limit the rubygems_update to < 3.0 and bundler to < 2.0.